# Where is located the default auth:api middleware?

Tags: laravel, api, middleware

I'm building an API and I'm using the API route file that Laravel provides.

That's the default route that comes with the `api.php` file inside the `routes` folder.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

But when I try to access the API I get this error:

> Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::__construct(): Argument #1 ($provider)
> must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given
> called in
> ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php

I also tried to add my own route to my controller:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/signin', 'Api\ControllerSignin@signin');
```

But I get the same error.

**My question is:**

Where is this `middleware('auth:api')` located and how can I get it working?

Comment: What authentication scaffold are you using? You need to be logged in for the route to work.

Comment: Thank you, @Unflux. I want to use a token based authentication for my API. Do you think it would be better if I create a custom middleware to check the token? If so, I wouldn't need guards, right? I created the custom guard but I get this error: `Auth driver [token] for guard [api] is not defined.` I have cleared the cache.

Comment: Even when I try to access the api route without any middleware I says `Auth guard [] is not defined`...is there any way to disable authentication for api routes?

Comment: Which auth scaffold are you using though, [`Passport`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) or [`Sanctum`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)?

Comment: None. I want to build a simple auth system.

Comment: You require some means of providing access tokens. Using one of the pre-built scaffolds is advisable over creating something yourself.

Comment: I see thank you. I will consider using Sanctun then, since it's more simple.